# Create a script to check multiple service accounts

Tags: command-line-interface

I'm looking to create a script that will be able to check multiple service accounts and output the results to then be emailed.

Within Command Prompt, I need to run the following commands:

```
Set "IsActive_svc=No"
Net User svc /Domain 2>Nul | Find /I "Account active" | Find /I "Yes" >Nul && Set "IsActive_svc=Yes"
```

This will check whehter the service account is active and update the variable to 'Yes' if the account is active. Now, I would like to do this for multiple service accounts. Here's my current attempt at writing a script to accomplish this:

```
_list_of_service_accounts_= "svc1|svc2|svc3"
for e in $__list_of_service_accounts_;
do
     Set x = isactive + e    // Declare new variable
     Set "IsActive_cicdprodsvc=No" // Set new variable equal to no
     Net User e /Domain 2>Nul | Find /I "Account active" | Find /I "Yes" >Nul && Set x = Yes // Change variable to Yes if account is active

done
```

I'm currently having errors setting the variables in the loop as well as creating a table that stores all of the outputs.

Comment: please check your code (including a first line of `#!/bin/bash`) at https://shellcheck.net. Fix the flagged items and if that doesn't solve your problem, update your code above and include exact text of any error messages, formatted with the `{}` tool on the Edit menu (as you seem to know how to use). Good luck!

Comment: _list_of_service_accounts_= "svc1 svc2 svc3", this can be looped.

Comment: That is not bash, it looks like windows batch...